# Minecraft Command to trigger a command(s) when i'm on a specific block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm trying to make a horror map and there is this one block I want that if you are on that block, it triggers a command and doesn't trigger again unless i set it up again. I looked it up and couldn't find any help. This is for **Java 1.20** and I want to do this with command blocks or in chat.

I'm not the best with commands so if anyone can help me, you'll be saving my map!

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! On Minecraft commands questions, please see our [guide on what to do before asking a Minecraft commands question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797), especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”, and [edit] in the requested information to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `/execute at @a if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:tnt run kill @s`...
Replace `tnt` with anyblock you want get checked.
Replace `kill @s` with anycommand you would like to run.

Comment: Do I run this on a command block or in chat? Or both?

Comment: You can do both.